# Regex Parsing failing to parse links

Tags: javascript, regular-expressions

Here is the discrepancy

[image]

Here is the parser

```
function addPhoneLinks(str) {
(str.match(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})/g) || []).forEach(tel => {
    str = str.replace(tel, `<a href="tel:${tel}">${tel}</a>`);
});

return str;
```

}

Here is the string it is parsing

```
<p><b>State Contacts</b></p> <ul><li>Corporate: 612-122-1000</li><li>Colorado: 990-222-1102</li><li>Michigan: 772-000-1122</li><li>Minnesota: 612-215-5300</li><li>New Mexico: 806-378-2714</li><li>North Dakota: 701-371-5254</li><li>South Dakota: 605-366-1265</li><li>Texas: 806-378-2714</li><li>Wisconsin: 715-737-2565</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String#replace takes a regular expression as an option. This should avoid any problems:

```
function addPhoneLinks(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})/g, `<a href="tel:$1">$1</a>`)
}
```

I presume the problem occurred because the number appears twice in the list, which means the first instance gets replaced twice (and the second not at all), causing the problems you see here.

Original output:

```
<li>
  New Mexico: 
    <a href="tel:<a href="tel:806-378-2714">806-378-2714</a>">806-378-2714
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks again fox